# My jQuery script only works for one element and not the other

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a digital sign that runs an HTML page that shows an iframe every thirty seconds. I have some jquery that cycles images. The script works for the first element but not the second that has the same class. I'm I doing something wrong? I've been searching the internet trying to fond the answer. I've added a new return statement to the function to include the second element with no success. I've also tried changing them from classes to IDs and calling both, but still haven't gotten anywhere.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color: #FFFFFF;
                height: 1080px;
                width: 1920px;
            }

            ul {
                list-style-type: none;
            }

            .frame {
                width: 1920px;
                height: 1080px;
                /*z-index: 9999;*/
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
            }

            .logo {
                margin-top: 20px;
                margin-left: 20px;
                z-index: -9999;
                height: 159px;
                width: 700px;
            }



            .product-pics {
                float: right;
                /*margin-top: -10%;*/
                height: 70%;
                width: 40%;
                z-index: -9999;

            }

            .product-pics > h1 {
                font-size: 6em;
                text-align: center;

            }

            .product-pics > ul {
                /*height: 50%;*/
                margin-top: -20%;
            }

            .power-point {
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
                height: 83.33333333333333%;
                margin-bottom: -50px;
                z-index: -9999;
            }

            .weather {
                float: right;
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
                right: 0;
                margin-bottom: -50px;
                z-index: -9999;
            }           

            #slider {
              margin: 10px 0;
              width: 100%;  /*Update to your slider width*/
              height: 100%;  /*Update to your slider height */
              position: relative;
              overflow: hidden;
              z-index: -9999;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="timer = setTimeout('auto_reload()',60000);">
        <!--Logo-->
        <div>
            <img src="logo.png" class="img-responsive logo">
        </div>
        <!--Product pics-->
        <div class="col-lg-5 product-pics">
            <ul class="slider">
             <li>
               <img src="Agitator_W.jpg" class="img-responsive">
             </li>
             <li>
               <img src="DSC01196AW2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
             </li>
             <li>
               <img src="ez-strainer 1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
             </li>
             <li>
               <img src="formfit_3249A.jpg" class="img-responsive">
             </li>
             <li>
               <img src="drumsaver steel 2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
             </li>
             <li>
               <img src="smart_pail_8R.jpg" class="img-responsive">
             </li>
             <li>
               <img src="steel drum 2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
             </li>
            </ul>
            <h1><b>Welcome To<br>CDF</b></h1>
        </div>
        <!--PowerPoint-->
        <div class="col-lg-7 power-point">
            <ul class="slider">
             <li>
               <img src="Slide1.jpg" class="img-responsive">
             </li>
             <li>
               <img src="Slide2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
             </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="weather">
            <span style="display: block !important; width: 320px; text-align: center; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px;"><a href="http://www.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/findweather/getForecast?query=zmw:02360.1.99999&bannertypeclick=wu_clean2day" title="Plymouth, Massachusetts Weather Forecast"><img src="http://weathersticker.wunderground.com/weathersticker/cgi-bin/banner/ban/wxBanner?bannertype=wu_clean2day_cond&airportcode=KPYM&ForcedCity=Plymouth&ForcedState=MA&zipcode=02360&language=EN" alt="Find more about Weather in Plymouth, MA" width="300" /></a><br><a href="http://weathersticker.wunderground.com" title="Get latest Weather Forecast updates" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px">Click for weather forecast</a></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <iframe src="http://live.deckmonitoring.com/?id=cdf" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" class="frame"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // code for image slider
    jQuery(function($) { 

      // settings
      var $slider = $('.slider'); // class or id of carousel slider
      var $slide = 'li'; // could also use 'img' if you're not using a ul
      var $transition_time = 0; // 1 second
      var $time_between_slides = 4000; // 4 seconds

      function slides(){
        return $slider.find($slide);
      }

      slides().fadeOut();

      // set active classes
      slides().first().addClass('active');
      slides().first().fadeIn($transition_time);

      // auto scroll 
      $interval = setInterval(
        function(){
          var $i = $slider.find($slide + '.active').index();

          slides().eq($i).removeClass('active');
          slides().eq($i).fadeOut($transition_time);

          if (slides().length == $i + 1) $i = -1; // loop to start

          slides().eq($i + 1).fadeIn($transition_time);
          slides().eq($i + 1).addClass('active');
        }
        , $transition_time +  $time_between_slides 
      );

    });

    // code for autoreload
     var timer = null;
            function auto_reload()
            {
              window.location = 'http://192.168.0.236/cdf_front_display/front_display.html';
            }
    //code for the iframe        
    $frame = $('.frame');

    var timeIn = setTimeout(function() {
        $frame.hide();
    }, 30000);


    var timeOut = setTimeout(function() {

        $frame.fadeIn();
    }, 60000);
</script>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

Here is an example of what I'm seeing
https://jsfiddle.net/goffley3/0L1tp9tb/2/

The issue is that I have two ULs with the same class that contain two or pictures and I'm trying to cycle through them like a slide show. What's happening is that the jQuery script I have is only working on one of them and not the other. The other just displays the first image in the list and doesn't cycle at all.

Comment: That's a fair bit of HTML. You'll get better responses if you make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: If you let it loop through all of the images in the first section, does it *then* loop through the other section?

Comment: You need to be more specific as to what is working for the first element and not the second.  Also, which elements are you talking about?  You've given us a lot of code here with only a vague explanation of what it is supposed to do and no indication of what is wrong beyond "doesn't work".  Please narrow it down so we can help you.

Comment: Please create this demo in jsFiddle.net. You'll get a lot more help and have to do less explaining.

Comment: A working example in a fiddle with minimal code will help us help you!

Comment: I added a fiddle, sorry about that. @Ishettyle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This what you wanted? https://jsfiddle.net/0L1tp9tb/5/

```
$($slider).each(function () {
```

Is the key.

Comment: That did, thanks a lot. Sorry for the bad explanation.

Comment: So are we using the each method because after it finds the first element the script stops? This way it keeps iterating? @chris

Comment: Never mind I saw that, I added another of the same element after the second list to see if it worked. Thanks again. I'l remember next time.

Comment: No it is because your function to return the elements you wanted to work with only returned 1 set of elements. And in this case it returned the last one - your second set of images. What the each does is it allows us to handle each set on their own, so that each function will only run twice, the rest is done by your timeout function we bind. If you want to chat more about it I am in the HTML / CSS / WebDesign live chat at the moment.
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign

Comment: I don't have twenty or more rep points. I understand what you're saying however. you're saying that the each methods will allow me to iterate through each element that has that class vs only returning one UL set. Thanks again for the help.